# How do I stop DataContext.CreateDatabase creating a clustered index for the primary key of a table?

Tags: linq-to-sql

When using DataContext.CreateDatabase() to create a database, I wish to stop Linq To Sql creating a clustered index on the primary key of  a table.

This is because I wish to create a normal index for the primary key, as I need the clustered index to spread up range queries on a date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that  you can't control what DataContext.CreateDatabase Does.